# Can not connect to database in mySQL server using phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried everything to add the data to database but it fails to connect

Apache phpMyAdmin is being used. Am unable to connect to the data base

connect.php

```
<?php    
include('dbcon.php');
$uname= $_POST['username'];
$cname= $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$pass= $_POST['password'];
$number= $_POST['number'];

$query= "INSERT INTO `userlogindata`(`username`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `number`) VALUES ('$uname','$cname','$email','$pass','$number')";


$run=mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($run==true)
{
?>

            <script> 
            window.open('redirect.php','_self');
            </script>

<?php
}
else {

?>

            <script> alert('Login-Id is already !');

            window.open('index.php','_self');
            </script>
<?php

      }

?>
```

dbcon.php

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','onlinetest');

if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

?>
```

It shows an alert Log-Id already registered.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Seems like you're query fails. Add some proper error handling after making the query and check why it fails. Read about [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) in the manual

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I understand, and I know about MD5 and other encryption algorithms, but it isn't that concern, Iam unable to connect to database!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried that, but I guess its about connectivity! Can you help me out!

Comment: _"I know about MD5"_ - That's not what you should use though. Please read my comment again. Anyway, since you're not getting "Failed to connect ...", the issue is most likely _not_ the connection, but the query, which you need to debug. Anyway, you should rewrite your code to use prepared statements and hashing the passwords before continuing. No reason to debug and make insecure code work since you still would need to rewrite it.

Comment: @Shailesh200: (1) MD5 is not an encryption algorithm.  (2) MD5 should not be used for password hashing.  (3) Don't *assume* that these things are not the problem if you haven't debugged and confirmed what the problem is.  According to the description your query is simply returning `false`.  That doesn't mean you *can't connect*.  It means the query *failed*.  But since you are wide open to SQL injection, you *aren't in control of the query*.  So what SQL code did you execute and what error did it return?  You need to discover those things.

Comment: Where in all of this is phpmyadmin?

Comment: Don't use JavaScript for redirects. But that is the least of your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you should look into prepared statements, but to get your errors from the connection you need to ensure you call of your `$con` variable. Atm you are using

`echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;`

It should be

`echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;`